# linking google adwords conversions to IDs

Tags: google, google-analytics, google-ads

I have a four page funnel and I have conversion tracking code on the second page. On this second page a lead # is generated and all subsequent pages of this funnel add data to this lead #.

I'd like to be able to see what keywords specific members used to see my ads. Is this possible with AdWords and if so, how? Or maybe this would be easier with Google Analytics?